# time series analysis problem with lagged residuals

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I am dealing with time series analysis, I want to check residual autocorrelation, but before that I would like to draw time series lag plots and I am struggling with problem like that

[image]

lagged residuals seem to be the same as residuals:

here is the code:

```
ehata=ts(DATA1$residuals, start=c(1960), end=c(2015),freq=1)
plot(ehata,xlab="",lwd=2,col="red")
abline(h=0) 
plot(lag(ehata,-1),ehata,ylab="residuals",xlab="lag",lwd=2,col="green")
```

btw residuals time plot works

```
ehata=ts(DATA1$residuals, start=c(1960), end=c(2015),freq=frequency(DATA1))
plot(ehat,xlab="",lwd=2,col="red")
abline(h=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider adding data to your question to reproduce the problem. You can get the sample data by running `dput(DATA)` in your RConsole.

Comment: What's the question exactly? Without any of your data we can't run your code, so it's unclear what you're trying to do or whether the residuals do match. If the issue is more about the analysis than the code, it's better suited for [stats.se], but they'll probably want more information as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.